# Apply a rank across groups

Tags: r, dplyr, ranking, rank

I cant seem to get this working. I'd like to rank a variable based on max value in a range of years. I can rank within a group ok, but I cant seem to be able to assign the ranking across groups.

It needs to be a dplyr mutate solution if possible as I am piping this into a plot.

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(
    YEAR = c(2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L), 
    Grp = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
    Value = c(25L, 24L, 35L, 34L, 45L, 44L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Table looks like this:

| YEAR | Grp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | A | 25 |
| 2019 | A | 24 |
| 2020 | B | 35 |
| 2019 | B | 34 |
| 2020 | C | 45 |
| 2019 | C | 44 |

I'd like to create the following output that ranks the Grp based on the value of the maximum year - in this case 2020.

| YEAR | Grp | value | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | A | 25 | 3 |
| 2019 | A | 24 | 3 |
| 2020 | B | 35 | 2 |
| 2019 | B | 34 | 2 |
| 2020 | C | 45 | 1 |
| 2019 | C | 44 | 1 |

Comment: Do you mean `data %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% mutate(Rank = rank(-Value)) %>% ungroup()`?

Comment: That doesn't rank the Grp though.

Comment: What if the years in `Grp` C is 2019 & 2018, do you still take the value the of the maximum year (i.e. 2019)?

Comment: Yes will take the value of the max year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Grp) %>%
  mutate(Rank = Value[which.max(YEAR)]) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Rank = dense_rank(-Rank))

#   YEAR Grp Value Rank
# 1 2020   A    25    3
# 2 2019   A    24    3
# 3 2020   B    35    2
# 4 2019   B    34    2
# 5 2020   C    45    1
# 6 2019   C    44    1
```